# How to prove this involving sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $a,b,c$ be $3$ positive numbers.

Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a^n+b^n+c^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\max\{a,b,c\}$$
Thank you for your time

How can I generalize this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: [This](https://notgnoshi.github.io/l-infinity-norm/) answers your question.

Comment: @LukeCollins i have tried saying things like Without loss of generality let a>=b>=c then we have equaling a as such from the definition but i was stuck on how to resolve |(a^n+b^n+c^n) ^(1/n)-a| i from my above statement we have the previous absolute value less than or equal to |a(3)^(1/n)-a| this is less than |a-a|=0 but from this i couldnt find an N,

Comment: @user71381 The $N$ would come from the $N$ of $\sqrt[n]3\to1$. Do you know how to prove that?

Comment: @LukeCollins no, I'm simply new to sequences and real Analysis

Answer (score 1):

Suppose wlog that $\max\{a,b,c\}=a$. Then
$$|\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n+c^n}-a|\leqslant|\sqrt[n]{3a^n}-a|=|\sqrt[n]3a-a|\to0$$
since $\sqrt[n]3\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\Big(\max\{a,b,c\}\Big)^n<a^2+b^2+c^2<2\times \Big(\max\{a,b,c\}\Big)^n$$
for large enough $n$.